# Google App Engine exception when using objectify 6.0 - com.googlecode.objectify.LoadException

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blob, objectify

I am using objectify 6.0 to retrieve data from GAE datastore. The datastore table has 7 fields other than id, as below.

```java
package org.skoonline.atl.dataservice.entities;


import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Index;
import com.googlecode.objectify.Key;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob;
 

import java.util.Date;

@Entity 
public class SKOScriptHistory {
    //@Id String id;
    @Id Key<String> id;
    @Index String guid;
    User lastUpdatedBy;
    String notes;
    @Index Date timestamp;
    String scriptContent;
    Blob scriptContentBlob;
    String title;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "hello string";
    }
    
    public String getGuid() {
        return guid;
    }

    public void setGuid(String guid) {
        this.guid = guid;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public User getLastUpdatedBy() {
        return lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedBy(User lastUpdatedBy) {
        this.lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    
    public String getScriptContent() {
        return scriptContent;
    }

    public void setScriptContent(String scriptContent) {
        this.scriptContent = scriptContent;
    }
    
    public Blob getScriptContentBlob() {/// Changes
        return scriptContentBlob;
    }

    public void setScriptContentBlob(Blob scriptContentBlob) {/// Changes
        this.scriptContentBlob = scriptContentBlob;
    }
    
    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public Key getKey() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Using following line I am trying to retrieve a single row from the table

```java
SKOScriptHistory tmp = ofy().load().type(SKOScriptHistory.class).first().now();
```

But getting these exceptions

```java
com.googlecode.objectify.LoadException: Error loading Key..Expected type ENTITY at path '%' but instead found scriptContentBlob [BLOB]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected type ENTITY at path '%' but instead found scriptContentBlob [BLOB]
```

Full exception is below

```java
com.googlecode.objectify.LoadException: Error loading Key{projectId=backupsko-1470660825968, namespace=, path=[PathElement{kind=SKOScriptHistory, id=4645925137940480, name=null}]}: Expected type ENTITY at path '%' but instead found scriptContentBlob [BLOB]
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.EntityMetadata.load(EntityMetadata.java:84)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine.load(LoadEngine.java:196)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine$1.nowUncached(LoadEngine.java:154)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine$1.nowUncached(LoadEngine.java:140)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Round$1.nowUncached(Round.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.HybridQueryResults.lambda$load$1(HybridQueryResults.java:88)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$6.transform(Iterators.java:786)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:47)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$ConcatenatedIterator.next(Iterators.java:1372)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.computeNext(Iterators.java:636)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:141)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:136)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.HybridQueryResults.hasNext(HybridQueryResults.java:93)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.IteratorFirstResult.nowUncached(IteratorFirstResult.java:31)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.LoadResult.now(LoadResult.java:25)
    at org.skoonline.atl.dataservice.MyScriptsServlet.doPost(MyScriptsServlet.java:103)
    at org.skoonline.atl.dataservice.MyScriptsServlet.doGet(MyScriptsServlet.java:45)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsyncServlet.service(ServletHolder.java:1395)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1617)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1596)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1580)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1215)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected type ENTITY at path '%' but instead found scriptContentBlob [BLOB]
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:462)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslator.loadSafe(ClassTranslator.java:90)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.NullSafeTranslator.load(NullSafeTranslator.java:21)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.PropertyPopulator.setValue(PropertyPopulator.java:95)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.PropertyPopulator.load(PropertyPopulator.java:55)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassPopulator.load(ClassPopulator.java:119)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslator.loadSafe(ClassTranslator.java:113)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.NullSafeTranslator.load(NullSafeTranslator.java:21)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.EntityMetadata.load(EntityMetadata.java:80)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine.load(LoadEngine.java:196)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine$1.nowUncached(LoadEngine.java:154)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine$1.nowUncached(LoadEngine.java:140)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Round$1.nowUncached(Round.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.HybridQueryResults.lambda$load$1(HybridQueryResults.java:88)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$6.transform(Iterators.java:786)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:47)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$ConcatenatedIterator.next(Iterators.java:1372)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.computeNext(Iterators.java:636)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:141)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:136)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.HybridQueryResults.hasNext(HybridQueryResults.java:93)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.IteratorFirstResult.nowUncached(IteratorFirstResult.java:31)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.LoadResult.now(LoadResult.java:25)
    at org.skoonline.atl.dataservice.MyScriptsServlet.doPost(MyScriptsServlet.java:103)
    at org.skoonline.atl.dataservice.MyScriptsServlet.doGet(MyScriptsServlet.java:45)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsyncServlet.service(ServletHolder.java:1395)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1617)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1596)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1580)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1215)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am migrating google app engine application from Java7 to Java8 and very new to objectify. Is there anybody encountered similar problem? I appreciate any help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Objectify v6 doesn't know anything about the old `com.google.appengine.api.datastore` classes. So Objectify is trying to treat your Blob class as a normal embedded object ("expects ENTITY") when the database content is a `Blob` type.

The best thing to do is replace the Blob with a simple `byte[]`. But you can probably also replace it with this:

https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-datastore/latest/com/google/cloud/datastore/Blob.html

Note the `com.google.cloud.datastore` package.

BTW the "at path '%'" is a bug in the error message that has been fixed in v6.0.7.

Comment: Thank you much. It worked. I did not notice different datastore in the import statement.